# I need someone to explain for me this java code

Tags: java, android

I'm solving an exercise for my university and there is this code in my pdf that my supposed to use to delay the change of the colour of the text on a button, i don't understand how it exactly works so please can someone explain it

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("showText");
    handlerThread.start();
    Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int i = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            i++;
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            if (i > 1) 
                button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        }
    };
    handler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The code that you have provided is incomplete. A lot is happening in the`Handler` and `HandlerThread` classes, for which you didn't provide source code. You'd also need to precise which part exactly is unclear for you.

Comment: that's what we are provided after we are told that button is considered a Button view on our activity, i can partially understand the 'Handler' and 'HandlerThread' but i cant get my head around the usage of the integer i and why we need to use it @MirekPluta

Comment: It's definitely not how scheduled tasks should be implemented. I'd say that this code is quite messy. It calls `handler.postDelay` from within `run` method, which I assume will call this run method again in 1000ms (because it passes `this` reference). That `int i` is probably meant to guard that `button.setTextColor` won't execute at first execution of `run`. However, it'll keep executing every second infinitely. That's not good way to write code, I'm not sure where did you take it from, but don't follow such practices.

Comment: @MirekPluta it is what we were given and yes you are right I loged what i needed and i saw its entering an infinite loop. do you have any suggestion how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is in obscure way causing that Runnable to be called with the delay of 1s (every second) because it reschedules itself each time. The `int i` is guarding `button.setTextColor` from executing the first the.

This code is however very messy, the way it should be done is as follows:

```java
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

or with lambda expression just as following:

```java
        handler.postDelayed(() -> button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)), 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks man appreciate it